# keep getting 'ImportError: No module named pygtk' when I try to run Gaphor on windows

Tags: python, pygtk, importerror

I have installed pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.0.win32-py2.7.msi on windows, and installed gaphor by easy_install. When I try to run gaphor, I receive an import error.

```
PS C:\Python27\Scripts> .\gaphor.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\gaphor-script.py", line 9, in <module>
  load_entry_point('gaphor==0.17.2', 'console_scripts', 'gaphor')()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 521, in   load_entry_point
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2632, in load_entry_point
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2312, in load
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2318, in resolve
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gaphor-0.17.2-py2.7.egg\gaphor\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  import pygtk
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually install pygtk? I suspect easy-install should have pulled it in automatically. Did you see any errors during the install? pygtk also requieres installing gtk+.

Do a simple test - start Python in a console (ipython?), and type:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, May  6 2014, 10:57:58) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygtk
>>> import gtk
>>>
```

There should be no error messages.

You can also search the disk for pygtk.py (with the file manager) and for a directory gtk-2.0 or gtk-3.0.